# Knockout js end of dependency chain not updating

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm currently trying to run some calculations using Knockout js. My problem is that the last of the calculations aren't updating in the UI. Basically I have three payment fields that are calculated based off of the total price so that the user could make payments in differing amounts. Payment1 is equal to the memberBalance, but if the user changes the payment1 then payment2 is calculated as the memberBalance - payment1. Similar with payment3, if payment2 is updated by the user, the payment3 = memberBalance - paymentAmount1 - paymentAmount2. Here is my code to show the scenario. I'm using mvc razor in the UI.

Here is an excerpt of my razor/html

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemberBalance,
new
{
   htmlAttributes = new
   {
       @class = "form-control",
       @id = "memberBalance",
       @name = "rg-from",
       data_bind = "value: memberBalance, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enable: false"
   }
})

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaymentAmount_1,
new
{
    htmlAttributes = new
    {
        @class = "form-control",
        @id = "paymentAmount1",
        @name = "rg-from",
        @data_bind = "value: paymentAmount1, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"
    }
})

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaymentAmount_2,
new
{
    htmlAttributes =
    new
    {
        @class = "form-control",
        @id = "paymentAmount2",
        @name = "rg-from",
        @data_bind = "value: paymentAmount2, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"
    }
})

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaymentAmount_3,
new
{
    htmlAttributes =
    new
    {
        @class = "form-control",
        @id = "paymentAmount3",
        @name = "rg-from",
        @data_bind = "value: paymentAmount3, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"
    }
})
```

And here is my ko view model

```
var viewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.pointsToBeRedeemed = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.vendorBookingAmount = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.transactionFeesDue = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.transactionFeesWaived = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.iceBookingFees = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.vacationCashRedeemed = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.pointsDiscount = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.internationalProperty = ko.observable();
        self.paymentAmount1 = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.paymentAmount2 = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.paymentAmount3 = ko.observable(startingValue);
        self.memberBalance = ko.observable(startingValue);

        self.memberBalance = ko.computed(function () {
            var international = (self.internationalProperty() == true) ? 0.05 : 0;
            return ((Number(self.vendorBookingAmount()) + Number(self.transactionFeesDue()) -
                Number(self.transactionFeesWaived()) + Number(self.iceBookingFees()) -
                Number(self.vacationCashRedeemed()) - Number(self.pointsDiscount())) +

                (Number(self.vendorBookingAmount()) + Number(self.transactionFeesDue()) -
                Number(self.transactionFeesWaived()) + Number(self.iceBookingFees()) -
                Number(self.vacationCashRedeemed()) - Number(self.pointsDiscount())) * international).toFixed(decimalPlace);
        }, self);

        self.paymentAmount1 = ko.computed(function () {
            return Number(self.memberBalance()).toFixed(decimalPlace);
        }, self);

        self.paymentAmount2 = ko.computed(function () {
            return (Number(self.memberBalance()) - Number(self.paymentAmount1())).toFixed(decimalPlace);
        }, self);

        self.paymentAmount3 = ko.computed(function () {
            return (Number(self.memberBalance()) - Number(self.paymentAmount1()) - Number(self.paymentAmount2())).toFixed(decimalPlace);
        }, self);
    };
```

My guess is that this is a dependency issue. I read that knockout won't make the calculation of one thing if it is in the process of calculating the same thing, which, I believe happens in this case. Is there anyway to circumvent that? I've looked into the peek() and subscribe functions, but unless I'm using them in the wrong way, they just seem to not update the field I am using them on. For example, if I use peek on memberBalance method within the payment1 function, then the payment1 function no longer updates, but the other two do and if I use peek within any of the methods for payment1 or payment2 I just get NaN returned. Subscribe has some weird behavior too. Maybe I'm too much of a newbie at ko, but there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of good documentation on this, but maybe I'm on the right track?

I'm also masking the fields using maskMoney if that matters at all, but I'm not doing anything to those fields that I'm not doing to the others. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems (to me) to be a problem that's not related to the knockout code, but with the logic and calculations.

1. `paymentAmount1` is basically the same value as `memberBalance`
2. `paymentAmount2` is therefore always 0
3. which makes `paymentAmount3` to be always 0 as well.

Please also bare in mind that when an observable holds a primitive value, it will not trigger updates if it's set with the same value.

If you want your observables to be "writeable", you'll have to specify `write` methods that invert the logic.

Also note that you've defined your `paymentAmount` 1, 2 and 3 and `memberBalance` twice: first as an observable, later as a computed.